# Dialogflow CX - list of strings as a parameter

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I'm building a chatbot in Dialogflow CX. I would like to save a parameter as a list of strings. The idea is that the user inputs the strings separated by a semicolon such as:
`string one; string two; string three`
and Dialogflow separates it like an array split by the semicolon
`["string one", "string two", "string three"]`

But I can't get it to work, it takes the full string as the first element of the array
`["string one; string two; string three"]`.
I have tried ticking the "Is List" checkbox and using @sys.func.SPLIT(@session.params.my_param, ";") on the route, to no avail.
Thanks!